# PHP $_SESSION data lost because frameset on IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session, session-variables, frameset

I would like to start saying that I had searched a LOT for this problem. After more than a week trying to solve it, I tihnk that I'm ALMOST there.

Yes, I do put session_start() - not only this, as I have session.auto_start On!

Some visitors access my site not using the www and others do. As throughout the visit they may expierence a change in the domain (from mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com and vice-versa) I get losing the $_SESSION data and many many erros occurs.

So I add this to my code:

```
session_write_close(session_id());
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.mydomain.com');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.mydomain.com');
session_start();
```

After some tests, I got it woking perfectly - since now - on Chrome and Firefox. The session ID and data keeps the same while change the domain. But - without surprise - it does not work on IE.

I have no clue since, in theory, PHP does not carry about the browser. So it sholud work whatever the user agent is.

On IE it changes from a session to another. It is VERY WEIRD. Here is what happens:

1. I visit mydomain.com/info1 and it loads many data into $_SESSION.
2. I visit mydomain.com/info2 and it overwrites the $_SESSION accordingly to the new data. Until here, everything is perfect.
3. But randomly, only on IE, sometimes the info about the /info1 shows and suddnely, it goes back to /info2.

As I use frameset, I think this is an important note from *php.net*:

> Session data is usually stored after your script terminated without the need to call session_write_close(), but as session data is locked to prevent concurrent writes only one script may operate on a session at any time. When using framesets together with sessions you will experience the frames loading one by one due to this locking. You can reduce the time needed to load all the frames by ending the session as soon as all changes to session variables are done.

I have made new tests *without* frameset and it worked on all borwsers, including IE.

Here is my php configuration for session:

```
Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  On  On
session.bug_compat_42   On  On
session.bug_compat_warn On  On
session.cache_expire    240 240
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    no value    no value
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  100 100
session.gc_maxlifetime  1440    1440
session.gc_probability  1   1
session.hash_bits_per_character 4   4
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /tmp    /tmp
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    Off Off
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

Comment: Why? `because frameset on IE`

Comment: This is a fantastic example of why nobody uses frames anymore.

Comment: @Sammitch: Not really. And what the OP is concerned about (quote from PHP.net), this does not lead to session loss, but blocking requests because of parallel requests.

Comment: Without knowning more about the structure of your frameset, it's hard to tell more. For case *"3."* you describe, it looks like that `/info2` has not been yet called when you are already at *"3."*. That might sound esoteric, but first comes first. Knowing more about the structure and processing you need could shed some light.

Comment: @Sammitch I can't change my whole front end code now. It has been done. I don't have the knowlodge to do that. I just want to fix it using backend programming.

Comment: @hakre: Let me try to explain in another way: 1) /info1 set $_SESSION[msg] = 'You are in page1'. Then I go to /info2 and it does $_SESSION[msg] = 'You are in page2'. Then randomly, while still on /info2 it shows 'You are in page1' then I reload (or keep navigatin on it) and it goes back to 'You are in page2'. Did yo ugot the mess? =/

Comment: Yes I already did understand your *problem* however to solve that some more information is needed to give some good advice or exposure some useful ideas. In which frameset are those pages opened? What is the frameset-structure?

Answer (score 1):

> Some visitors access my site not using the www and others do. As throughout the visit they may expierence a change in the domain (from mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com and vice-versa) I get losing the $_SESSION data and many many erros occurs.

This only a suggestion, I don't know but probably it helps. What you could do here if you have access to `.htacces` is to normalize the URLs how your website is accessed, especially the domain part with or without *www* with the help of [*Mod_Rewrite*](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This example would ensure that users will be always using your website with the `www.` subdomain instead of a mixture.

This is also generally good so you have only one domain for the site which can save some headaches.

Comment: Thanks a lot @hakre but I do not have access to .htacess. I can only add RewriteRule via Control Panel and by this method I can't add a RewriteCond neither use last and redirect together (opt for more than one flag). Anyway, this won't fix my problem, perhaps is a very good suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: For your problem I commented below your question as well. Without knowing more about the frameset structure and the processing you need there is not much to say. One solution *can* be that the frameset is generated by a PHP file that takes care of correct session initialization. But it's hard to say w/o knowing more.